# Slow plan to acces a View

Tags: postgresql

We have a somewhat complex table join and created a view to avoid writing it for every use. Simplified ...

```
create view MyView as
select b.id,b.customer_id,b.somedata,t1.moredata
from bigtable b
left join table1 t1 on t1.id=b.t1_id
```

When used on itself it works as expected and returns the rows in a few milliseconds.

```
select *
from MyView
where customer_id=somevalue    -- That's ok
```

But real life is not so simple. In fact we want to use it as part of a more complex query:

```
select *
from Customers c
left join MyView v on v.customer_id=c.id
where c.code=somecustomercode      -- Simple enough ... but problematic
```

We expected a fast answer, reading the customer table using an existing index and left joining the view with the customer already solved.

But it takes forever (bigtable has some hundreds thousand rows).

Using `explain` tells us why: the whole view is created first and the customer table join is performed as the last step.

Any idea on how to improve (make it work) ?

**Edited** to add (simplified) real view as well as explain text. We are using PostgreSQL 9.1.20. The real view is still more complex with two more tables, but this one has the same behaviour.

The view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MyView AS 
 SELECT trim(ip.res_id, 'res.partner,')::integer AS partner_id,
  ppli.product_id,
  ppli.fixed_price
   FROM ir_property ip
   LEFT JOIN product_pricelist ppl ON ppl.id = trim(ip.value_reference, 'product.pricelist,')::integer AND ppl.type = 'c'
      LEFT JOIN product_pricelist_item ppli ON ppli.pricelist_id = ppl.id AND ppli.product_id is not null
    AND now() between COALESCE(ppli.date_start, '2016-01-01'::date) AND COALESCE(ppli.date_end, '2099-12-31'::date)
  WHERE ip.name = 'property_product_pricelist' AND left(ip.res_id, length('res.partner,')) = 'res.partner,' 
    AND left(ip.value_reference, length('product.pricelist,')) = 'product.pricelist,';
```

Explain for the first (fast) select accessing the view directly using customer_id

```
select *
from MyView
where partner_id=12345

''Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.01..3920.07 rows=8 width=32)'
'  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.01..3897.79 rows=1 width=24)'
'        ->  Seq Scan on ir_property ip  (cost=0.00..3889.49 rows=1 width=42)'
'              Filter: (((name)::text = 'property_product_pricelist'::text) AND ("left"((res_id)::text, 12) = 'res.partner,'::text) AND ("left"((value_reference)::text, 18) = 'product.pricelist,'::text) AND ((btrim((res_id)::text, 'res.partner,'::text))::integer = 128930))'
'        ->  Index Scan using product_pricelist_pkey on product_pricelist ppl  (cost=0.01..8.28 rows=1 width=4)'
'              Index Cond: (id = (btrim((ip.value_reference)::text, 'product.pricelist,'::text))::integer)'
'              Filter: ((type)::text = 'c'::text)'
'  ->  Index Scan using product_pricelist_item_pricelist__product_index on product_pricelist_item ppli  (cost=0.00..22.06 rows=13 width=16)'
'        Index Cond: ((pricelist_id = ppl.id) AND (product_id IS NOT NULL))'
'        Filter: ((now() >= COALESCE(date_start, '2016-01-01'::date)) AND (now() <= COALESCE(date_end, '2099-12-31'::date)))'
```

Explain for the second (slow) select accessing the view as a join

```
select customer_id,v.*
from res_partner c
left join MyView v on v.partner_id=c.id
where c.ref='Code01'

'Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.01..3293.42 rows=1 width=1300)'
'  Join Filter: ((btrim((ip.res_id)::text, 'res.partner,'::text))::integer = rp.id)'
'  ->  Index Scan using res_partner_ref_index on res_partner rp  (cost=0.00..8.32 rows=1 width=1268)'
'        Index Cond: ((ref)::text = 'Code01'::text)'
'  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.01..3284.93 rows=8 width=32)'
'        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.01..3209.33 rows=1 width=24)'
'              ->  Seq Scan on ir_property ip  (cost=0.00..3201.03 rows=1 width=42)'
'                    Filter: (((name)::text = 'property_product_pricelist'::text) AND ("left"((res_id)::text, 12) = 'res.partner,'::text) AND ("left"((value_reference)::text, 18) = 'product.pricelist,'::text))'
'              ->  Index Scan using product_pricelist_pkey on product_pricelist ppl  (cost=0.01..8.28 rows=1 width=4)'
'                    Index Cond: (id = (btrim((ip.value_reference)::text, 'product.pricelist,'::text))::integer)'
'                    Filter: ((type)::text = 'c'::text)'
'        ->  Index Scan using product_pricelist_item_pricelist__product_index on product_pricelist_item ppli  (cost=0.00..75.43 rows=13 width=16)'
'              Index Cond: ((pricelist_id = ppl.id) AND (product_id IS NOT NULL))'
'              Filter: ((now() >= COALESCE(date_start, '2016-01-01'::date)) AND (now() <= COALESCE(date_end, '2099-12-31'::date)))'
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose) select ...` for both queries. Formatted text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: And Postgresql version

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't in your view... Does "customers" have indexes to "id" and "code" columns?

Comment: Yes, sure it has. id is the autogenerated key and has an indx. ref also as stated on the explain: Index Scan using res_partner_ref_index on res_partner